# Getting invalid address Web3 when creating a new task

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I’m developing a basic TodoList based on a tutorial of DAppUviersity on Youtube using Ethereum Blockchain, Solidity, and truffle , and I found this error when excepting the creatTask function, I tried every solution without any result, Any help, please

### app.js Code:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  init: async function () {
    await App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: async function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        "http://localhost:7545"
      );
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: async function () {
    $.getJSON("TodoList.json", function (TodoList) {
      const todoList = TodoList;
      App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(TodoList);
      App.contracts.TodoList.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      return App.render();
    });
  },

  render: async function () {
    if (App.loading) {
      return;
    }
    App.setLoading(true);
    App.account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    $("#account").html("Your Account: " + App.account);
    const todoList = await $.getJSON("TodoList.json");
    App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(todoList);
    App.contracts.TodoList.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
    App.todoList = await App.contracts.TodoList.deployed();
    App.setLoading(false);
    return App.renderTask();
  },

  renderTask: async () => {
    const taskCount = await App.todoList.taskCount();
    const $taskTemplate = $(".taskTemplate");
    const submitButton = $("#submitButton");
    for (var i = 1; i <= taskCount; i++) {
      const task = await App.todoList.tasks(i);
      const taskId = task[0].toNumber();
      const taskContent = task[1];
      const taskCompleted = task[2];
      const $newTaskTemplate = $taskTemplate.clone();

      $newTaskTemplate.find(".content").html(taskContent);
      $newTaskTemplate
        .find("input")
        .prop("name", taskId)
        .prop("checked", taskCompleted)
        .on("click", App.toggleCompleted);

      if (taskCompleted) {
        $("#completedTaskList").append($newTaskTemplate);
      } else {
        $("#taskList").append($newTaskTemplate);
      }
      $newTaskTemplate.show();
      submitButton.show();
    }
  },

  createTask: async () => {
    try {
      App.setLoading(true);
      const task = $("#newTask").val();
      console.log(task);
      await App.todoList.addTask(task);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },

  setLoading: function (boolean) {
    App.loading = boolean;
    const loader = $("#loader");
    const content = $("#content");
    if (boolean) {
      loader.show();
      content.hide();
    } else {
      loader.hide();
      content.show();
    }
  },
};

$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

### Solidity Code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
contract TodoList {
    uint256 public taskCount = 0;

    struct Task {
        uint256 id;
        string description;
        bool complete;
    }

    event TaskCreated(uint256 id, string content, bool completed);

    mapping(uint256 => Task) public tasks;

    constructor() public {
        addTask("Morning Coffee");
    }

    function addTask(string memory _description) public {
        taskCount++;
        tasks[taskCount] = Task(taskCount, _description, false);
        emit TaskCreated(taskCount, _description, false);
    }
}
```

> ```
> Hello Everyone,
> I’m developing a basic TodoList based on a tutorial of DAppUviersity on Youtube using Ethereum Blockchain, Solidity, and
> ```
>
> truffle , and I found this error when excepting the creatTask
> function, I tried every solution Hello Everyone,
> I’m developing a basic TodoList based on a tutorial of DAppUviersity on Youtube using Ethereum Blockchain, Solidity, and
> truffle , and I found this error when excepting the creatTask
> function, I tried every solution